# Halt PHP CLI script to give the user possibility to exit with CTRL-C

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-interface

How to pause the execution of a command line script to give the user the possibility to exit it with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

For example I have this script for deleting a user id from a number of tables, but would like to halt the script before really doing it:

```
<?php

define('DBHOST', '/tmp');
define('DBNAME', 'XXX');
define('DBUSER', 'YYY');
define('DBPASS', 'ZZZ');

$TABLES = array('pref_game',
                'pref_hand',
                'pref_luck',
                'pref_match',
                'pref_misere',
                'pref_money',
                'pref_pass',
                'pref_rep',
                'pref_status',
                'pref_users'
        );

if ($argc != 2)
        exit("Missing user id\n");

if (!preg_match('/^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]+)$/', $argv[1], $matches))
        exit("Invalid user id\n");

$id = $matches[1];
printf("Deleting user %s Press CTRL-C to abort\n\n", $id);

# XXX stop here, but how? XXX

try {
        $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=' . DBHOST . '; dbname=' . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        foreach ($TABLES as $table) {
                $sql = sprintf('delete from %s where id=?', $table);
                run_sql($db, $sql, $id);
        }

} catch (Exception $e) {
       exit('Database problem: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

function run_sql($db, $sql, $arg) {
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute(array($arg));
        printf("SQL: %s\nAffected rows: %d\n\n", $sql, $sth->rowCount());
}

?>
```

Using CentOS Linux 5.5 + PHP 5.1.6 + PostgreSQL 8.4.7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with:

```
    printf("Deleting user %s Press CTRL-C to abort, enter to continue\n\n", $id);
    $fp = fopen("php://stdin","r");
    fgets($fp);

    echo "OK!";
```

Answer (score 2):

`sleep(5);` would wait for five seconds.

If you want something more fancy:

```
function delay($duration) {
    while($duration) {
        echo "\rStarting in ".$duration--.'...';
        sleep(1);
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

---

If you don't want to sleep but prefer a yes/no-style prompt:

```
function confirm($question) {
    while(true) {
        $line = strtolower(trim(readline($question.'? [Y/n]')));
        if(!$line || $line == 'y') {
            return true;
        }
        elseif($line == 'n') {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for returning back and expanding your answer. I'll go with Francesco's answer though, because do not want to depend on readline

Answer (score 0):

Use `sleep()` or read from stdin until you get a newline: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Thanks, but do you have a 1-2 lines solution?